# how to find total transaction volume in web3

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I need to find the sum of ETH value transacted to and from a contract address in web3, like in last 24 hours. I have no clue to find it through web3 api. I am using web3 version 1.0. Can anyone help me here.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment since I don't have enough reputation, but I just want to propose a link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68012937/

It helped me reaching my goal and should help you too. You just have to get the events and sum their values.